# How to return a std::map item

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have an issue on returning an item from a std::map residing inside a class.
I am trying to create a simple function like

```
ExplorerObjectMapItem* MyClass::getFirst()
{
    mInternalMapIterator = mObserverLookup.begin();
    ExplorerObjectMapItem* item = &*mInternalMapIterator;
    return item;
}
```

where the following typedefs are used

```
typedef map< Subject*, shared_ptr<ExplorerObject> > ExplorerObjectMap;
typedef pair<Subject*, shared_ptr<ExplorerObject> > ExplorerObjectMapItem;
typedef ExplorerObjectMap::iterator                 ExplorerObjectIter;
```

and the map and iterator are class members:

```
ExplorerObjectMap                               mObserverLookup;
ExplorerObjectIter                              mInternalMapIterator;
```

The above code for the getFirst() function gives a compile error saying

```
E2034 Cannot convert 'pair<Subject * const,boost::shared_ptr<ExplorerObject>
 > *' to 'ExplorerObjectMapItem *'
```

Not sure what is going on here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: On a side note -- having a map with the key being a pointer is very error prone.  One such error is doing a find on a pointer value, and that pointer value is no longer valid.

Comment: I understand. The map is used in a Subject/Observer pattern. I had problems properly remove observers after the subject is gone. The map helps in that I am setting subject pointer to null when a subject is dying. Then a subsequent 'squeeze' function goes trough the map, removing all observers where a subject is null, and eventually the item itself. Not sure right now how to change it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::map<K,V>` does not contain `std::pair<K,V>` objects.  It contains `std::pair<const K, V>` objects.  That missing `const` is what throws off the conversion.

You could fix this with either

```
typedef pair<Subject* const, shared_ptr<ExplorerObject> > ExplorerObjectMapItem;
```

or

```
typedef ExplorerObjectMap::value_type ExplorerObjectMapItem;
```

Comment: Great! That was it. Making does changes seem  to fix the problem nicely.